# Western Digital My Book Does not Mount

Tags: 14.04, mount, hard-drive, ntfs

I am trying to mount a Western Digital My Book (which I believe is formatted as NTFS) on an up-to-date version of Ubuntu 14.04. When I boot it up, it shows in Nautilus on the side as "My Book" under devices, but when I click on it, an error dialogue pops up stating:

> Unable to access "My Book"
>
> Error mounting /dev/sdc2 at /media/lesk/My Book: Command-line `mount -t "exfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,umask=0077" "/dev/sdc2" "/media/lesk/My Book"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: unknown filesystem type 'exfat'

Is there any patch for fixing this? There is already data stored on the My Book that I need (it was added to the My Book on a Windows 10 system) so reformatting it is not an option.

If there is no patch for 14.04 to fix this, would upgrading to 16.04.1 do this any good?

Comment: Do you have extfat-fuse and extfat-utils installed? If not, it might help to install them with `sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils`

Answer (score 0):

Connect the WD drive back into a Windows environment, and note which drive letter it's assigned. Then in an administrative command prompt window, type:

`chkdsk /f x:`

replacing the "x" with the assigned drive letter for the WD.

When you're done, make sure that you properly eject the drive from Windows, using the green USB icon in the system tray, before pulling the plugs.